# how to solve the error that fs module is not found when used react and next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Am using a react application without router settings. I want to build my sitemap.xml file. I tried some modules like sitemap.js, react-router-sitemap, sitemap-generator. But these module are throwing error as fs module is missing. I installed fs module via `npm install --save`. But it is still showing the error.

I found in some forums to add  the below code in webpack.config file.

node: {
    fs: "empty"
   }
Am not sure where this file is. I couldn't find them nside the sitemap related modules.

Please help me to resolve this. Am new to react.

Here is my folder structure. 
[image]

Comment: React is a front end library. `fs` is the back end file system node library. Are you trying to do `fs` stuff in the front end in React? Please add the relevant minimal code of what you've done so far.

Comment: Am not using fs module . But i can find const fs = require('fs'); inside the sitemap-generator module. sitemap generating modules which i have listed above using fs module

Comment: Yes but those sitemap libraries *will* use the `fs` module. If you try to use them in, say, a front end file, then they'll try to run in the browser, and you'll get that error message. In which files did you try to make the sitemap when using one of those modules?

Comment: please check the folder structure which i have updated. Am running the sitemap script from pages/index.js file

Comment: And I assume the `index.js` file is the root of your React app?

Comment: Yes, its the root file

Comment: Ok so that's the issue. That code in `index.js` ultimately gets run on the client side, in the browser. Those node modules you're using like `sitemap.js` are SERVER side modules. Designed to run on the back end. You need to run them there. Do some research about front end vs. back end webapp development, specifically in Node. That should help clear up your understanding

Comment: So here do I want to call them directly from the module? Or need to create a new custome module?

Comment: I'm not sure what that question means exactly, or how it's relevant to the issue. Yes you can call those modules directly, but ONLY in a *back end* environment. Again, look into what I said, that should help clear things up.

Comment: I did some research on backend and frontend and came to know that we can use  getInitialProps function which is already in my index.js I added the below code  then also no luck, still showing fs module missing error.static async getInitialProps ({  }) {
      const SitemapGenerator = require('sitemap-generator');
      const generator = SitemapGenerator('http://localhost:3000', {
        maxDepth: 0,
        filepath: './sitemap.xml',
        maxEntriesPerFile: 50000,
        stripQuerystring: true
      });
      generator.on('done', () => { });
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173120/discussion-between-jayce444-and-prajila-v-p).

Comment: I'm also getting same error. I'm using next.js framework for SSR.

Answer (score 1):

create next.config.js and put below code. It works fine for me.

## next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
      // Note: we provide webpack above so you should not `require` it
      // Perform customizations to webpack config
      // Important: return the modified config

      // Example using webpack option
      //config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/__tests__\//))
      config.node = {fs:"empty"}
      return config
    },
    webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
      // Perform customizations to webpack dev middleware config
      // Important: return the modified config
      return config
    },
  }
```