# Cannot resolve 'fs' on static generate project

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I want to serve static file in my Next.js app and it is throwing me an error each time it wants to use import fs from 'fs';

I'm supposed not obligated to yarn add fs in order to use fs, why is it giving me this?

My next.config.js is pretty much empty:

```
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');

module.exports = {
  ...nextTranslate(),
};
```

My current dynamic post page is:

```
/** @format */
import fs from 'fs';

export default function Doc() {
  return <div>Enter</div>;
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

Still I get this error:

[image]

I even tried to start a new project and it fails too once I try to use fs. Does it needs to be installed globally in my computer? I have node (v14.15.1) installed for sure.

Comment: It seems your code is executed on the Frontend? Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830572/how-to-solve-the-error-that-fs-module-is-not-found-when-used-react-and-next-js ?

Comment: You can't use NodeJS modules like `fs` from the browser. JavaScript running in the browser isn't allowed to access the filesystem, for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

`fs` is a module that is built into Node.js and depends on Node.js APIs.

It cannot run in a browser. So it cannot run in a typical React component.

You can use it [in a server-side only module in Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12124) but if you want to use it in a component then you'll probably need to replace it with an HTTP module like Axios and write a server-side endpoint to request your data from.